# how to return a loosely-typed object?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, visual-studio-2017

**How do we avoid breaking changes in a controller method, when the database schema changes?**

Suppose I am returning an object:

```
public class Bike
{
   public int Wheels {get;}
   public int Id {get;}
}
```

in the following controller:

```
public class BikeController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Bike> Get([FromBody] MyRequest request)
    {
        var context = new DbContext(_repository.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
        var procedure = request;
        return context.Database.ExecuteStoredProcedure<Bike>(procedure).ToList();
    }
}
```

At some point, the database code changes. **I don't want to have to redefine the Bike schema in C#.**

**How do we change the signature of the Bike controller method, in order to not have any breaking changes, when the database schema changes?**

I'm looking for something like the following:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    var context = new DbContext(_repository.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
    var procedure = request;
    return context.Database.ExecuteStoredProcedure<object>(procedure).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Are you concerned that the controller method will break, or are you concerned about clients of the API that might break if the object returned is changed?

Comment: @ScottHannen thank you for your response. i was not clear and i've updated the question. i'm concerned that the developers would have to update the models to reflect database schema changes, i dont watn to have to do that and instead return a weakly-typed object

Comment: Depends on how clients consume your api. Say if you return object as json - most clients won't care about additional field and its unlikely to break anything. If you remove field though - that's of course breaking change.

Comment: @Evk i dont want to return Bike at all, i want to return dynamic or object or something abstract, is that possible?>

Comment: I suspect he's calling .ToList because he's returning List<...> Change your return type to IEnumerable<...> then you won't need .ToList.

Comment: @n8 IEnumerable of what? object?   _IEnumerable<object>_ ??

Comment: I'm still stuck on determining the purpose of `var procedure = request;`

Comment: @RufusL im sorry about that, just updated the question thank you

Comment: Doesn't your `ExecuteStoredProcedure` has version which does not require providing type parameter? One that returns `dynamic`, or `Dictionary<string,object>` or just `object`?

Comment: @evk no it does not

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' that is the reason for `IHttpActionResult` abstraction. you can call `return Ok(resultObjectHere);` or which ever response is appropriate and given that you are not directly accessing any properties on the object, the change you proposed should be decoupled enough given the current information provided.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why your controller at all need to change since you are just returning the retrieved type directly without referring any of it's properties in your action method.

Moreover, why you are calling `.ToList()` when you are returning a single `Bike` object. Further more, you may consider using a Model or ViewModel instead of returning the entity directly as an option.

@Evk already pointed that a newly added property would just get lost while deserializing but if you want to return a abstract object then you can have all your entity inherits from a `BaseEntity` having common property and return that instead like

```
BaseEntity obj = context.Database.ExecuteStoredProcedure<Bike>(procedure);
returb obj;
```

Comment: but wouldnt this break: _return context.Database.ExecuteStoredProcedure<Bike>(procedure).ToList();_ ??

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''', why? if your DB schema changes then anyway you will have to refresh your application schema ... hopefully you are using EF

Comment: nope i am going directly to the database, i dont want to have to recompile my code

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''', no that won't be possible since then the actual schema changes won't be reflected. If you really want that then try using a `Expando` object

Comment: it seems like what i am suggesting is definitely not a standard approach to the problem, but nevertheless, it's surprising to me that there's not more information on how to create a READONLY contrller method that doesnt care about the type that it is returning and simply return json from the database

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a few alternatives:

1. Return `dynamic` instead of `Bike`. However, this has a performance impact on all users of the `dynamic` objects.
2. Return `object` instead of `Bike`.

But in both cases your Bike stored procedure will still return the updated data which won't be compatible with the `Bike` object, so you will still need to recompile the controller.

2. Return a standard object that represents the `BikeController` response and matches the stored procedures response.

Consider how you handle database updates in SQL - your SELECT statement specifies the exact columns you need and is unaffected by schema changes that don't affect the returned columns, or if you are using `*` you ignore any columns you don't need, which isn't conducive to strong typing or ORMs.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't access any property or use any method its existence is dependent on a schema object or anything related to the database You are on the safe side.
Making the controller agnostic to the database schema, will make it very unlikely that this controller will be changed due to changes on the database side, and that's why the `Data Access layers` are made.
I think if we applied separation of concerns principle we would see that it is not the `Controller` responsibility to deal with the database, this must be done through some kinds of `Brokers` like a repository interface type injected into the controller constructor. The controller will just see insert, update, delete methods but it doesn't have any knowledge about the database.
Also, it's not a loosely-typed object. It's a loosely coupled types what you really need.

Comment: i disagree with your last statement

Comment: Why? this is not a loosely-typed? you don't want to create a loosely-typed objects in a language which is characterized by being `Strongly typed` language.

Comment: You're not accessing any property or make use of any `method/property` which depend on the database right? then, there is no need to create a weakly typed object!

Comment: i agree that it's bad design, but the boss is the boss

Comment: Oh, I see! You must be in a very tough situation. I hate dogmatic bosses!

Comment: LOL! indeed! i will look up loosely coupled types thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are simply retrieving an object from the database, the number of properties which comes inside the object wont effect or break your ActionMethod.

If you are still worried for a reason like the properties inside your object are not what you want to render on the view then you can use a ViewModel and use your Bike objects properties to populate the viewmodel and render the viewmodel instead.

Comment: if the database will return an extra field for Bike, then context.Database.ExecuteStoredProcedure<Bike>(procedure); will not show that field, right?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' depends on what your SP is doing, if it is simply selecting all values for a specific id then it would return all values for that id.

Comment: when you make a change to your database, for example you add another field to the bike table then you have to update your edmx file and once you update the edmx file, your model which is the Bike class in c# will be updated by entity framework

Comment: nope, if the field is not defined in Bike, then it will not return that field

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' if you are using entity framework then you dont have to define the new field yourself, when you update your edmx file, the new field will be added to your Bike class by entity framework